# android.view.View.sendAccessibilityEventUncheckedInternal error only HTC One Mini

Tags: android

Hi I got this error from Fabric. It's only come from "HTC one mini" . Why did you come ?? It is a specific error this model ??

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
   at android.view.View.sendAccessibilityEventUncheckedInternal(View.java:5020)
   at android.view.View.sendAccessibilityEventUnchecked(View.java:5001)
   at android.view.View$SendViewStateChangedAccessibilityEvent.run(View.java:19761)
   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5872)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Method.java)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:858)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:674)
   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(NativeStart.java)
```

Comment: Did you get a solution to this?? I'm also getting this error in some devices.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't understand but our user removed [360 Security](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.qihoo.security&hl=tr) app and application run perfect.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's an old question but I stumbled upon the same problem and I found that answer which helped me : https://stackoverflow.com/a/20892109/2637428

I'm commenting this issue as it was the first one I found before finding the other one.