# Strange package found in app exception stacktrace

Tags: android, exception

I got the following exception stacktrace from one of my app (got it in the google developer console, so some (relatively few) of my users are getting this exception, but i am not able to reproduce it on the emulator or on my devices):

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android.support.v7.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.initializePanelMenu(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:1038)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.preparePanel(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:1102)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.doInvalidatePanelMenu(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:1399)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.access$100(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:89)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7$1.run(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:126)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:808)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:103)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5292)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:824)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:640)
    at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.main(XposedBridge.java:132)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

What the hell is XposedBridge? Only one stacktrace had the line with the XposedBridge stuff. Is it an hack?

Comment: Related, can be of help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20429603/android-4-4-kitkat-random-crash

Comment: "What the hell is XposedBridge?" -- it is a class that is part of [the Xposed framework](http://repo.xposed.info/module/de.robv.android.xposed.installer). "Is it an hack?" -- it is software, installed on rooted devices, that modifies the behavior of all apps.

Comment: If only there was a place on the internet where could enter terms like "android robv xposed" and it would tell you what they are...

Comment: @CommonsWare Can you tell me more about it? What means that modify the behavior of all apps? Some examples? Thx

Comment: @323go Maybe Stackoverflow is one of those places? :P

Comment: "Can you tell me more about it?" -- I gave you a link to it. I have never used it.

Comment: @323go It is not really about laziness, speaking with someone about a topic you do not know anything about is usually faster than searching with google. Just to make a quick idea of what we are talking about.

Comment: Did you solve it? I'm getting a crash report about `Xp0sedBridge` in my crashlytics report.